# How can i check if user input is empty (react)

Tags: reactjs, react-redux

1. so i have a basic todo react app and how can i check if the user enters an empty value
2. How can i also make sure that the empty todo dosent get added to the todolist

Comment: Please add your code. Then we can help you...

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please take the [tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) have a look around, and read through the [HELP center](http://stackoverflow.com/help), then read [How to Ask Question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), [What types of questions should I avoid asking?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask) and provide a [MCVE: Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). If people around can easily read and understand what you mean, or what the problem is, they'll be more likely willing to help:)

Answer (score 2):

Provide us a sample code that you are working with, it will be easy for us to suggest things.

Assuming you using class component. In `addTask` method you can check if the user has entered the text or not.

```
export default class App extends React.Component {
  state = {
    list: [],
    task: ""
  };

  addTask = () => {
    const { task, list } = this.state;
    if (!task) {
      alert("Please enter a task");
      return false;
    }

    this.setState({ list: [...list, task] });
  };

  render() {
    const { task, list } = this.state;

    return (
      <>
        <input
          value={task}
          onChange={e => this.setState({ task: e.target.value })}
        />

        <button onClick={this.addTask}>Add task</button>

        <ul>
          {list.map(task => (
            <li>{task}</li>
          ))}
        </ul>
      </>
    );
  }
}
```

https://codesandbox.io/s/intelligent-yonath-clken?file=/src/App.js:51-736

Comment: This is what i have so far

https://codesandbox.io/s/mystifying-dew-0gcmt?file=/src/App.js

Answer (score 0):

I think what you require is similar to below code,
just check if trimmed value is not equal to "", then the trimmed item is added in your list.

```
function addItem() {
if(inputText.trim()!==""){
  setItems(prevItems => {
    return [...prevItems, inputText.trim()];
  });
  setInputText("");
}
}
```

Also make sure to save the index.js so that server is restarted before trying to access the App on local port.